# How do I create a new group?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, administration, groups

In my SharePoint, I have no "site permissions" tab under settings. I am unsure how to create a group other than the following way:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions

Is there another way to create groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One:**

1. First, you must ensure that you have **Full Control** permission to support you create a SharePoint Group.
2. Then, you can go to site permissions page directly using the URL: **https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_layouts/15/user.aspx**
3. You could click on **Create Group**

[image]

**Two:**

1. Sign in [Microsoft 365 admin center](https://admin.microsoft.com/) as SharePoint administrators or Grobal administrators
2. Click on **Groups** >> **Active groups** to creat a group.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need Full Control permissions on the site. Then, you will be able to see 'People and Groups' option in site settings which will allow you to create a new group.

Answer (score 1):

To create a group & grant permissions, you need a permission level that includes permissions to `Create Groups` and `Manage Permissions`. The **Full Control** level has both.

Also, You can go to site permissions
page directly using the URL in this format:
`<siteUrl>/_layouts/user.aspx`

Check this [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-SharePoint-site-permissions) to create a SharePoint Group.